# Perl: replace value in a hash of array with scaler references

Tags: perl, hash, reference

Trying to replace a null value with a known trusted value in this hash.  I am doing so but b/c of my s/.../.../g for ( @...) statement its printing dup values so maybe I am going about this all wrong since I searched and searched.  Here is my code please offer your help.  Thank you!

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $hmc01 = qq(rsqxxxx.xxxx.com);
my $key   = qq(/home/root/.ssh/id_rsa_hmcscan);
# get frame names
push my @frames, qx(ssh -i $key hscroot\@$hmc01 lssyscfg -r sys -F 
name|sort);
chomp @frames;
my (%cpudata,$h,$cpus,$max);
my $cspu  = q|configurable_sys_proc_units|;
my $caspu = q|curr_avail_sys_proc_units|;
# get cpu attributes for each lpar on each frame
foreach my $f (@frames) {
    open ( my $FD, "-|", "ssh -i $key hscroot\@$hmc01 lshwres -r proc -m 
    $f --level sys -F $cspu,$caspu" ) or warn $!;
    print  "\nFrame $f has,$cspu,$caspu,";
    for my $fdln (<$FD>) {
        my $cspu2  = +(split /\,/, $fdln)[0];
        my $caspu2 = +(split /\,/, $fdln)[1];
    }
    open ( my $FDD, "-|", "ssh -i $key hscroot\@$hmc01 lshwres -r proc -m 
    $f --level lpar -F 
    \"lpar_name\\;curr_proc_units\\;curr_max_proc_units\" ") or warn $!;

    # POPULATE in format name,cpu,maxcpu
    my ($h,$ccpu,$mcpu);    
    while (( my $fddln = <$FDD> )) {
        $h    = +(split(";", $fddln, 0))[0];
        $ccpu = +(split(";", $fddln, 0))[1];
        $mcpu = +(split(";", $fddln, 0))[2];
        push @{$cpudata{$h}}, ($ccpu,$mcpu);
    }
}
# REPLACE
foreach my $lpar (sort keys %cpudata) {
    if ( grep /null/i, @{$cpudata{$lpar}} ) {
        #my $lop = $lpar;
        ($new) = qx(ssh -i $key hscroot\@$hmc01 lshwres -r proc -m RSQ-20-p8408-44E-SN783739X --level lpar --filter \"lpar_names\=$lpar\" -F \"curr_procs,curr_max_procs\");
        #s/null/$new/g for @{$cpudata{$lop}};
        @{$cpudata{$lpar}} = map { s/null/$new/r } @{$cpudata{$lpar}};
    }
    print "$lpar,", join(",",@{$cpudata{$lpar}}),"\n";
}

use Data::Dumper;   print Dumper \%cpudata;
## INCORRECT b/c of DUPED output
'wassapxxxx' => [
'6,8
',
'6,8

'
],
## CORRECT OUTPUT
'twccntxxxxx' => [
'0.2',
'2.0
'
],

# %cpudata, raw
# 'wassapxxxxx' => [
# '2.5',
# '4.0
#'
#],
# wassapxxxx' => [
# null',
# 'null
#'
#                        ],
# 'rsqgangliaxxx' => [
# '0.5',
# '2.0
#'

# output of system call top-to-bottom
# lssyscfg -r sys -F name|sort
# IDI-8202-E4B-SN10AAF0B
# RSQ-17-p8286-41A-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-18-p8286-41A-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-19-p8408-44E-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-20-p8408-44E-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-21-p9009-41A-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-22-p9009-41A-SNxxxxx
# RSQ-DR01-8202-E4C-SNxxxx
# WilData-8202-E4C-SNxxxxx

# lshwres -r proc -m RSQ-22-p9009-41A-SNxxxxx --level lpar -F 
# "lpar_name;curr_proc_units;curr_max_proc_units"
# DTMiSeriesTxx;0.1;1.0
# NWSPRDxx;0.1;1.0
# MXDPRDxx;0.2;2.0
# TWCICOPE3xxx;0.1;1.0
# vios2xx;1.0;2.0
# R2iSeriesRsxxxx;0.1;1.0
# vios2xxx;1.0;2.0
# wassapdxxx;null;null
# wassapxxxx;null;null
```

for certain nodes I have to use variable curr_procs,curr_max_procs 
and not curr_proc_units;curr_max_proc_units, hence the variable $new. I am not sure what else to add, I think the code is pretty clear.  Please be specific so I can as well!  Thx!!

Comment: Can you show the content of the `%cpudata` hash before you enter the last `for` loop (the replace loop)?

Comment: Can you indent and clean up the posted code and output? It's hard to read it this way, and I don't know whether the shown output is indeed what you have (spaces and linebreaks included).  More importantly, you really should reduce the code to the simplest version that displays the problem.  We cannot test what you have with that `ssh`, for example.  (Also, in the process of reducing the problem you may well find the error.)

Comment: see edited code, now.  If I can clarify more, let me know!

Comment: I don't see problems with the critical code section -- print `$new` itself before using it in substituion; it's suspect.  (For one thing, it appears that you have linebreaks in it.)

Comment: @dirman I am curious, how did this go?  Did you add a line to print `$new` (before it is used in substitution) and did that reveal anything?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the comments above, that the code is hard to read and therefore to understand and that your data structure is not described exactly...

You want to substitute the scalar value `'null'` by the value in `$new`, right? Is a regular expression required or is a enough to replace the value if it is `'null'`:

```
if ( grep /null/i, @{$cpudata{$lpar}} ) {

    # why are your storing $lpar in $lop?
    my $lop = $lpar;

    # $new has to use unique variables for specific data #
    $new = qx(ssh -i $key hscroot\@$hmc01 lshwres -r proc -m RSQ- 
    20-p8408-44E-SNCCCCCCC --level lpar --filter \"lpar_names\=$lop\" -F 
    \"curr_procs,curr_max_procs\");

    ## maybe map will do the substitution in case you do not need
    ## a regular expression, just use 
    ##     { ($_ eq "null") ? $new : $_ }
    ## as map instruction
    @{$cpudata{$lop}} = map { s/null/$new/g } @{$cpudata{$lop}};
    }
```

Edit: Your edit showed, that you need to replace `"null\n"`. Therefore you might want to delete the line break and therefore use `s/null\s*/$new/g`. Btw... You are expecting a single substitution, thus the `/g` is not required.

Comment: The `s///` returns number of substituions made, so your `map` will return those numbers and overwrite the arrayref elements with them.  You can do what you want with `s///r` where `/r` modifier has it _return_ the changed string (or the original if no changed occurred). Before this was introduced (v5.16?) you needed  `map { s/../../g; $_ }`

Comment: This still uses the (same) regex but in a `map` instead of in `s/../../g for @ary` ... I don't understand the point?

Comment: I tried using the /r and its still printing dups.  see above for more info. Thx!